# PHP MySQL Active Record criteria sum

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

I have two tables, users and visits. I want to select all users who have 'active' in the visits table's status field, with a count of all visit records regardless of active/inactive status.

This query would only give me a count of 'active' visit records

```
SELECT 
     users.user_id, 
     COUNT(visits.id) 
FROM users u 
JOIN visits v ON v.user_id=u.user_id 
WHERE visits.status='active'
```

I was thinking of a subquery, or a php loop but worried about performance if the users table grows. If subquery's the best solution please post the active record code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub-query will be more efficient than looping in the code. I'd suggest this query:

```
select u.user_id, ucount
from users u
join (
      select user_id, COUNT(id) as ucount
      from visits
      group by user_id
     ) all
ON u.user_id = all.user_id
join visits v
on v.user_id=u.user_id
where v.status='active'
```

And if you need only user_id and no users.* field, then you don't have to join to users table (inspired by answer from arunmoezhi):

```
select user_id,count(*) as visit_count
from visits v
join (
  select user_id from visits
  where status ='active'
) act
on v.user_id=act.user_id
group by v.user_id;
```

Edited for formatting.

Comment: The subquery works in an active record join statement using the surrounding parenthesis. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id,count(*) as visit_count
from visits 
where user_id in(
select user_id from visits
where status ='active'
)
group by user_id;
```